# Angular: Using a global styles css for my library: the correct approach?

Tags: angular, sass

As you can't load a global scss file into angular.json for a library (Angular CLI says nonono), I took following approach for my library:

1. In my src folder, I still added a styles folder, containing my global scss (imports, variables etc)
2. I declared all my variables on :host instead of :root (I want to use root, but they aren't being parsed that way)
3. In my components typescript files, I add a new line in the Component decorator.styleUrls array: the link to my global styles

This is working. When I import my components from my library into my main application, I see the stylings applied. But for some reason, all global styles get embedded into each and every component. This not only bloats my dist files, it could also potentially slow down my browser, since it now has to evaluate all css on a component-level.

Please note that I do not want to load the SCSS in my main application. It will tightly-couple the library to the application, making it less suitable for distribution.

Would it be a better idea to have a different styles library and load this in parallel with my component library?

Is this the correct approach? Can you suggest me a better way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'library'?

Comment: @Nitika ng generate library